# How to implement custom pagination by the number of elements starting from a certain element?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Can anyone tell me how to implement pagination using spring boot and hibernate and interface JpaRepository<T, ID>?
It is necessary that there be a breakdown not by pages, but by the number of elements.
Example: here is a simple code example

```
@GetMapping("/persons")
list<Person> find everyone(
@RequestParam(required = false, default value = "0") int page,
@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "10") int size) {}

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

if page value 2 and size 3 are passed, then the elements should be displayed in order from 3rd to 5th (element 3, element 4, element 5). It should also be possible to pass any sort.

I used a `Pagerequest.Of(2, 3 Sort.by("any sort"))`. But the result I get is not exactly what I want. In this case, the elements are divided by page and are displayed from the 7th to the 9th element.
I tried it like this:

```
List<Person> person = service.find All(Page Request.of(0, page + size, Sort.by ("any sort").descending()));
return persons.subList(page, Math.min(page + size, persons.size()));
```

In this case, I get the result that is required, but there is one problem too much data is being unloaded, which is sorted. If you pass 1000 to the page variable, and 3 to the size variable, then 1003 elements are unloaded for the sake of 3.
Of course , you can write your query using LIMIT and OFFSET , but how can you do it without writing a native query ?

I tryied to find the answer in stackoverflow but without success. Although there are some answers but that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: In Spring pages count from 0. So with PageRequest.of(2, 3, Sort.by("anything")) you will get pages 6,7,8 (counted from 0).

Comment: Right, but to be precise pages 7,8,9. i'd like to get pages 3,4,5 with PageRequest.of(2, 3, Sort.by("anything"))

Comment: For 3,4,5 use PageRequest.of(1, 3, Sort.by("anything"))

Comment: Start page 0 = 0,1,2 start page 1 = 3,4,5 start page 2 = 6,7,8 etc

Comment: Don't pay attention to the numbers. If the page value is 2 and the size value is 3, I will get 7, 8,9. In this case, I need 3,4,5 elements. If the page value is 10 and the page size is 3, I get 31,32, 33, but I need to get elements 11, 12, 13 in this case